# How to use server IP with gunicorn and nginx

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, server, gunicorn

I’m definitely a newbie when it comes to ubuntu/Linux hosting of a Python flask app with gunicorn and nginx. Can’t figure out how to get it all working.

Everything I see online of how to set up flask/gunicorn/nginx uses a cloud VPS that has a distinct IP but I have a powerful physical server with ubuntu that I’m trying to use instead.

I followed Digitaloceans guide on this, minus the cloud VPS. I made it to the end and my app currently runs within the network (on 10.0.0.80) but I cannot figure out how to make it run on my PC server’s IP address. I know what it is but I can’t find out how to attach it to the rest.

if I was able to link the hardware IP to  nginx/gunicorn, I could simply add an A record in my domain registrar settings that points to the IP, but I cannot get that working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) specific details about the config you tried and the results you observed. There are apparently one or more web pages you consulted when trying to make your config work properly -- cite your references.

Comment: @J_H It's exactly the Digitalocean guide, besides the cloud VPS part of it.

Comment: Cite your reference already. What URL corresponds to the "cloud VPS" part of "the Digitalocean guide"? This is the web of 2023, though some of us are stuck in the '80s. Why talk _about_ a page when you can _link_ to it?